How do I decode AAC-ELD audio data to PCM data with AudioToolbox?
I can decode AAC_LC audio data but can't do it for AAC_ELD, the following is the code to create the converter, but I get an error "1724924917868" for AAC_ELD that means format not supported.
    _sampleRate = 44100;
    AudioConverterRef converter = NULL;
    inputFormat.mSampleRate = _sampleRate;
    inputFormat.mFormatID =  kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC_ELD;
    inputFormat.mFormatFlags = 0;
    inputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
    inputFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1; 
    inputFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16; 
    inputFormat.mBytesPerFrame = (inputFormat.mBitsPerChannel / 8) * inputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    inputFormat.mBytesPerPacket = inputFormat.mBytesPerFrame * inputFormat.mFramesPerPacket;
    inputFormat.mReserved = 0;
    
    AudioStreamBasicDescription destinationFormat = {0};
    destinationFormat.mSampleRate = inputFormat.mSampleRate;
    destinationFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = inputFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    destinationFormat.mFormatID          = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    destinationFormat.mFormatFlags       = (kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked);
    destinationFormat.mFramesPerPacket   = 1;
    destinationFormat.mBitsPerChannel    = 32;
    destinationFormat.mBytesPerFrame     = destinationFormat.mBitsPerChannel / 8 *destinationFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    destinationFormat.mBytesPerPacket    = destinationFormat.mBytesPerFrame * destinationFormat.mFramesPerPacket;
    destinationFormat.mReserved          =  0;
    self.pcmFormat = destinationFormat;
    
    OSStatus status = AudioConverterNew(&inputFormat, &destinationFormat, &converter);
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating audio converter: %d", (int)status);
        return NULL;
    }

I expect converter to be created without errors
